# What is the difference between open class and abstract class?

Tags: kotlin, abstract-class

```
abstract class ServerMock(param: String) {
   protected var someVar = params + "123"

   fun justMyVar() = someVar
}
```

Usage example:

```
class BaseServer(param: String) : ServerMock(param) {
   val y = someVar
}
```

Can this class be marked as `open` and not `abstract`?

What is the difference between `open` and `abstract` class?

Comment: Short answer: `open` CAN be subclassed, `abstract` MUST be subclassed. - Subclassing an `abstract` class might require that some methods be implemented, whereas an `open` class, being able to be instantiated on its own, can always be trivially subclassed without modification.

Answer (score 25):

`abstract` class cannot be instantiated and must be inherited, abstract classes are `open` for extending by default. `open` modifier on the class allows inheriting it. If the class has not `open` modifier it is considered final and cannot be inherited.

Answer (score 7):

You can not instantiate an `abstract` class. You either need to subclass or create an anonymous class using `object`. In `abstract` classes you can just declare function without implementing them (forcing the subclass to imlement them) or provide a default implementation.

```kotlin
abstract class BaseClass {
  fun foo() // subclasses must implement foo
  fun bar(): String = "bar" // default implementation, subclasses can, but does not have to override bar
}

// error: can not create an instance of an abstract class
val baseClass = BaseClass()

class SubClass : BaseClass {
  // must implement foo
  override fun foo() {
    // ...
  }

  // can, but does not need to override bar
}

// declaring an anonymous class (having no name) using object keyword
val baseClass: BaseClass = object : BaseClass {
  // must implement foo
  override fun foo() {
    // ...
  }

  // it is optional implementing bar
  override fun bar(): String {
    return "somethingElse"
  }
}
```

A class that is neither `abstract` nor `open` is considered to be final and can not be extended.

If you want to allow subclassing you should mark it open.

```kotlin
class AClass

// error: This type is final, so it can not be inherrited from.
class BClass : AClass

open class CClass

class DClass : CClass
```

So if you want to allow `BaseServer` to be subclassed you should mark it `open`. If you also want to declare functions, but force subclasses to implement them you can replace `open` with `abstract`.

**Documentation**

- [Kotlin Abstract Classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#abstract-classes)
- [Kotlin Inheritance (incl. open)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance)

Comment: I appreciate your thoughtful examples!

Comment: One advantage of abstract class over open class is if it implements an interface (or extends another abstract class) it does not need to implement all required functions itself in which case it forces subclasses to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine you have 2 classes

1. Class Person [parent class]
2. Class Coder [sub/child class]

When you want to inherit **Coder** from **Person** you have to make **Person** *open*, so it is available to inherit from.
Meanwhile you can make objects from **Person** itself.

When you don't need to make objects from parent class(in our case it's **Person**) or you don't see any meaning creating objects from it you can use *abstract* instead of *open*.

It works the same way as *open* does. But the main difference is that you cannot make objects from **Person**(parent class) anymore.